# Store non-strings in Hyperledger Fabric 1.4

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

From what I'm reading, it is only possible to pass string values from the Node SDK to the chaincode via [submitTransaction](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/module-fabric-network.Contract.html#submitTransaction).

However, from the chaincode point of view, there is no issue with creating an asset containing, say, booleans and integers and store them.

Hence my question: is storing non-string attributes considered a bad practice, and if not, what is the best way to implement it? Of course I can send strings that the smart contract will then convert back to bool/ints, but that sounds quite ugly. I also guess that instead of sending `...args` I can send a JSON, but again, quite ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always going to need to do some type of conversion | serialization/deserialization between the client and the actual chaincode itself.

Chaincode itself only accepts arrays of bytes as arguments.  If you have simple/primitive types for your arguments (string, int, boolean, etc), then passing them as strings from the client and converting them in the chaincode itself is the most straightforward approach.  I admit it's not super clean, but given we support clients and chaincode in multiple languages and allow you to mix and match, we can't use a language's native serialization for types.

Comment: I think at somepoint in time, it would be nice if language specific serialization is supported. Imagine just being able to send out Java object, get it on the other side and use it. So much of boiler plate coding would be eliminated. Not sure what complexity this means to HLF for it to handle, but excellence not only lies in the marvel that is created, but in the ease of use also.

Comment: I will say that we should expose the ability to directly send bytes though.  This way you could pick a language agnostic serialization such as protobufs, ASN1, etc

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is from JAVA HLF implementation standpoint. Assuming Node JS and Java have the same capabilities, the 'putState' method takes in either 'byte' or 'String' data types, and putState is the only method as far as I know to put data to ledger. So, you cannot put anything other than String/ byte in my view. So, although it is ugly, I think putting String or bytes to ledger is the only way to put and get data (at least as of HLF 1.4).

All data written to ledger would actually get stored onto 'CouchDB' behind the scenes, so if you write JSON strings to ledger, you can later write 'CouchDB query' and get the data from ledger too (just like how you use SQL to get data from traditional RDBMS).

Comment: I think we are not talking about the same thing, I guess I put a bad title. Let's say I want to store `{id: 'ABC123', available: true}` in the blockchain. In the chaincode, let's say I have a smart contract `save(ctx, id, available)`, which calls `putState` on the serialised JSON, on this we agree and it works. However, my question is how, *from my app*, using Node SDK, I can pass a boolean as an argument when calling `save`.

From what I read the only way from the app is `submitTransaction('save', id, available)`, which only takes ints. Sure, I could use JSON argument but it seems hacky.

Comment: Yes, I don't think data types are supported that way yet. In case of Java, I was wondering if HLF (as of 1.4) could take in Java object directly instead of 'string only'. That would reduce a lot of boiler plate coding too.

Comment: See my response below as to what we cannot / do not support native objects or language-specific serialization

Answer (score 0):

The point is you want to store non-string data types to the ledger.But right now,the Node JS / Java SDK only supports the `putState` method only takes string or bytes.

https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-chaincode-node/release-1.4/api/fabric-shim.ChaincodeStub.html

For example, if you want to put Number or boolean on the `putState` method.So on the SDK side at the `submitTransaction` ,you have to `JSON.stringify` the input data (if it's not a String data type).Unfortunately,this is the only way we have right now.